# Xcode: NSRangeException during DataCore migration

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, database-migration

When I test migration on an app using a mapping model where I have downloaded it from App Store it migrates successfully, but if I attempt to do so when I have changed the data before migrating it crashes with the following error:

2015-10-22 10:50:27.761 CREW Emergency Preparedness[240:5906] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1838d4f5c 0x1984cbf80 0x183850b60 0x10039b9e0 0x10039aa9c 0x1003ae214 0x1000eed48 0x100151274 0x1001517c0 0x188e2b610 0x188ee87e8 0x188ee86cc 0x188ee7920 0x188ee74e4 0x188ee710c 0x188ee7074 0x188e26ff0 0x18862df14 0x188628b20 0x1886289e0 0x18862807c 0x188627dd0 0x1886214bc 0x18388bc30 0x1838899d4 0x1837b8de0 0x188e980ac 0x188e92f44 0x1001273d0 0x198cf68b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

The statement it crashes on is:

```
try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:true])
```

How can I get this migration to complete?

### Update

I did not include the rest of the code because I had just inserted that statement into standard appDelegate.swift code but here it is:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)

    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("CREWData.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true])
    } catch var error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

Comment: Looks like you've got an empty array somewhere. You might want to throw in a break point before that method is called and see what's empty. `[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'`. Additionally, I'm not sure what the rest of your try statement looks like, but here's a post re: error handling in Swift 2.0 that you might find helpful. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/error-handling-in-swift-2--cms-25096

Comment: How can I check the array? I don't see why there should be a problem since the migrate works as long as I do not have any data in the app before I migrate but this is my first attempt to migrate Core Data and I am far from an expert in this area.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but the empty array jumped out at me. Have you looked at this RW migration tutorial? It's pretty recent. http://www.raywenderlich.com/114084/core-data-migrations-tutorial-lightweight-migrations

Comment: I spent a long time looking at this tutorial but it doesn't address the problem of migrating an app where there is data in the database. I've also looked at the Apple Developer documentation and from what I can see this ought not to be an issue. Thanks.